# HTML select tag with multiple selections? possible?

Tags: html

I'm looking for HTML list tag where user can select several options from the list, similar to `<select>` tag with the exception of selecting several options at once

What I'm looking for exactly is something very similar to jList in Java, which the list displays several options at once (unlike the `select` tag) and contains a scrollbar, and the user can select multiple options at once, like this:

[image]

Is there such thin HTML or Javascript? or is it available as a plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `multiple="multiple"` as an attribute to your `<select>`

Comment: adding to that, you can use the size attibure like size="4" to get the same height effect as jList.

Comment: I never knew that a single attribute will complete change the select tag to a list tag!